# Prevent WebView reloads in FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I have a FragmentPagerAdapter used to show about 6 tabs, all of which load their data from a web server. One of the tabs contains a WebView that loads an image from my server. **The server side costs of generating the image are high, and thus I want to reduce the number of calls to reload the WebView.** For the non-WebView tabs, I have been able to save my state (for those, just a simple array) and restore them as tabs get swiped through.

**Problem:**

- WebView reloads every time I swipe back to it using FragmentPagerAdapter, leading to high reload times and high load on my web server.

**Solutions Considered:**

- Use [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)
  This is problematic because it will force more tabs to be loaded, even if they are never going to be viewed. This is needlessly expensive on my server.
- Use [WebView.saveState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [WebView.restoreState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#restoreState%28android.os.Bundle%29)
  The documentation has been updated to make it clear display state is no longer maintained here, so this is no longer useful for this scenario.
- Set my activity to have: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
  This works for the rotation case, but doesn't affect the ViewPager/FragmentPagerAdapter swiping through tabs case.

It sounds like the old behavior of [WebView.saveState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29) would have been perfect...

Comment: I'd start by figuring out what in your fragment is triggering the reload. `WebView` itself is oblivious to pagers and fragments, so somebody somewhere is doing something to the `WebView` to trigger the reload. Then, you can work on trying to suppress this behavior.

Comment: In onCreateView, I have the following:
    wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.radarWebView);
            if(savedInstanceState != null) {
             wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            } else {
        wv.loadUrl(myURL);
            }

Comment: The main thing is swiping away causes the Fragment to be destroyed as I understand. When it comes back, it tries to restore state, but since the WebView is no longer able to restore display state, it has to reload (this is as best as I understand).

Comment: "The main thing is swiping away causes the Fragment to be destroyed as I understand" -- not with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. `FragmentPagerAdapter` is an "Implementation of PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment that is persistently kept in the fragment manager as long as the user can return to the page." "In onCreateView, I have the following" -- have you determined that `onCreateView()` is being called each time you swipe, even for a previously-viewed page?

Comment: I know onResume and onCreateView gets called once the tab gets past the limit of setOffscreenPageLimit().

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are wiping out your own results.

While you need a new `WebView` on a configuration change, you do not need a new `WebView` otherwise. And, if you already have the `WebView`, you do not have to tell it to do anything.

So, I'd try this:

- Hold onto the `WebView` that you create in `onCreateView()` in a data member of the fragment
- Only inflate the layout in `onCreateView()` if that data member is `null`
- Only call `loadUrl()` if you inflated the layout

(if you are creating the `WebView` in Java code, replace "inflate the layout" with "create the `WebView` via its constructor")

If the contents of the fragment is more than the `WebView`, you will also need to hold onto the root view that you inflated in a data member, so you can return that from `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Given the WebView is just one of several views in the fragment which is inflated via XML, what approach would you recommend?

Comment: @DerekJohnson: Hold onto the root view you inflate. Only inflate if that is `null`. Only call `loadUrl()` if you inflate.

Comment: When I hold the entire view in a instance variable, upon re-adding I get: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. I know I need to detach the view onStop() but getView() and getParent() offer no removeAllViews() or removeView().

Comment: @DerekJohnson: Cast the `ViewParent` returned by `getParent()` to a `ViewGroup` and call a suitable remove method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Mark, I had a similar problem with a WebView inside a FragmentTabHost and your suggestions worked a treat