# WebView reloading when Fragment in ViewPager is retained form BackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-viewpager, back-stack

Here is a code for a basic `Fragment` which contains a `WebView`.
`WebFragment.java`

```
public class WebFragment extends Fragment {
String TAG = "WebFragment";
private WebView webView;
private String currentUrl = "http://www.google.com";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_layout, null);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.helloWebview);
    initWebView();
    webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private void initWebView() {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Loding...");
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    });
}

class JavaScriptInterface {
    public void showHTML(String html) {
    }
}
}
```

I have 2 more basic fragments also(which doesn't have `WebView`). Then I put all these 3 `Fragments` in `ViewPager`(`WebFragment`, `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`respectively) using `FragmentAdapter`. And I added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`(So `WebView` will not realod on configration change).
Now my problem is, While running app I changed the 1st page (WebFragmet) of `ViewPager` to 2nd page(`Fragment1`) and again I came back to 1st page. So no problem `WebFragment` is as it is. 
Now again I changed the `ViewPager` like this `WebFragment`-->`Fragment1`-->`Fragment2` and came back to 1st page by reversing the direction of above action. But at that time I saw the `WebView` in `WebFragment` is reloading.

And one more problem, whenever the `WebView` started loading I can see 2 log entry like.

```
WebFragment Loading...
WebFragment Loading...
```

So my question is :
1) How can I prevent `WebView` reloading when the `WebFragment` is retained from `BackStack`?
2) Why here `WebView` loading twice?

Just see this question and help me([Prevent WebView reloads in FragmentPagerAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552377/prevent-webview-reloads-in-fragmentpageradapter)).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your main activity where you have defined viewpager

after the declaration of viewpager like this line : 
`ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);`

add this line :

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

This will prevent your fragment from recreated upto swipe of two screens,so when you will return from 3rd page to 1st page in viewpager,your webview will not reload.

Comment: @Chirag Shah actually I know this(`viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`) but If I have 5 or more `Fragments` in my `ViewPager` with `WebView` if I set `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5+);` ,It will be a bad option, rigth? What you say?

Comment: Can you answer for my 2nd question?

Comment: can you explain how is it bad to set offscreenlimit?I think it will good to prevent your fragment from being recreated.Isn't it?And im not sure about your second question?May be coz you are caling initWebView() method and also written this line : webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
so its called twice.@VishalVijay

Comment: @Chirag Shah, I didn't called ` webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);` in `initWebView()` so it should not call twice.

Comment: @Chirag Shah, the problem of using `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5+);` is memory and performance. if I set 5+ as off screen limit. All the 5+ `Fragments` will be there in memory so `Android` may have performance issue in low specification device.

Comment: @VishalVijay i didn't said you are calling  webView.loadUrl(currentUrl); in initWebView().
I said you are calling initWebView() and also calling webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
so Log "WebFragment Loading..." printed twice.

Comment: @Chirag Shah, I got the reason for my 2nd question. I added that with your answer. Thank you.

Comment: After surfing and reading loads of pages, I am saying this "The best Answer"

Comment: I don't like and supose change concept about fragments, and inconvenients : if you have a video (videView/YoutubeFragment) you will get a milions of errors to stop/streaming, my point of view

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic case of falling victim to the easy patch-fix of overriding `android:configChanges` to solve a problem.  Unfortunately there are multiple reasons why a config change will occur.  So simply catching for a screen size change will miss a lot of them...as you have discovered.

First, completely remove `android:configChanges`. Then add the following to your `WebView` fragment.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  webView.saveState(outState);
}
```

Adjust your WebView fragment's `onActivityCreated` method to include the following:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.helloWebview);
    initWebView();

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    else
        webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
```

}

That should get you going in the right direction.  Note, calling a `WebView`'s saveState() will not save display data. Eg, input tags will not perserve user input.  You'll need to parse through the webpage manually to persist that data. Depending on what you are using the WebView for, this will be a major pain.

Answer (score 2):

Well for fragments use like this.

```
A extends Fragment

{

   static  WebView w;

   View v;

   private Handler handler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {

        switch (message.what) {
            case 1:{
                webViewGoBack();
            }break;
        }
    }

    private void webViewGoBack() {
        w.goBack();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState){

 v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webs, container, false);

 w=(WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

//w.loadUrl("");

}

 w.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

 @Override

 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&& w.canGoBack())

            {

                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

                return true;

            }
            return false;
        }

     });
```