# HorizontalScrollView onTouch

Tags: android

I Am using Horizontal Scroll View and its work fine , i have 2 web view inside my horizontal Scroll View  , my problem is that when u scroll down or up in the web view sometime it go left or right to the other web view because of the Horizontal Scroll View , i use this code

```
HorizontalScrollView hv = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView2);
    webView22.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
private String TAG;

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.v(TAG,"PARENT TOUCH");
            findViewById(R.id.webView22).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
    webView22.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private String TAG;
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            Log.v(TAG,"CHILD TOUCH");
             //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
            findViewById(R.id.webView23).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

when i use the TAG i got error say The field **FragmentActivity**.TAG is not visible

but when i add the private String TAG; it go , anyway i am not sure if it is correct ,

How ever after i test it the `webView22` is good and great but if i want to go right and left using the Horizontal it will not be work ,

i tried to change the CHILD TOUCH to **BUTTON_BACK** but still the same . i feel that tag not doing anything it just go to

```
   findViewById(R.id.webView22).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
   return false;
```

i hope some one can help

Comment: better you use viewpager rather HorizontalScrollview

Comment: i don't know how to use weview in the viewpager when i ever try to but webview inside the viewpager i get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the case here is that both the horizontal scroll view and the web view consume the scroll event. Now it will be hard for the Android OS to decide onto which listener should this scroll event go to.

An option to this will be using Slide animations instead of a horizontal scroll view.

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_bottom_in,
                                               R.anim.slide_bottom_out,R.anim.slide_bottom_in,
                                               R.anim.slide_bottom_out);
```

But these will again need to be triggered with some event. like button click.

Or you can go  for the [view pager implementation.](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager)

Comment: thanks bro . yeah i think i will go for the view pager , its hard in this way

Comment: If that servers your purpose, you can accept this as an answer... It will help others also with same issue...

Comment: i try the view pager , and i but my webview in fragment . but when i swipe from tab one to tab tow , then swipe back again to tab 1 the webview will start again from the first link , i don't want it to change can u help me please in this and i will accept this as answer `

Comment: It's because your fragment is recreated, Check out this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272884/webview-reloading-when-fragment-in-viewpager-is-retained-form-backstack jus one line of code, and you have it solved... :)

Comment: Kailas , u make my day , love u bro , and thanks sooooooo soooo much u are amazing ,
am shy to ask u again but if u know how to solve this 

i have different project with one activity i have a button , this and 2 webview , i use HorizontalScrollView to go between them , the button will be handling the InterceptTouchEvent
so when someone touch the button the InterceptTouchEvent will work and , and when it touch again the InterceptTouchEvent will not work

i do the first touch its work , but when u retouch the button it will not stop the InterceptTouchEvent 

this is what i try

Comment: this is the code i try

HorizontalScrollView hv = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView2);
    imgbt1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
private String TAG;

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.v(TAG,"PARENT TOUCH");




            findViewById(R.id.webView22).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;

            return false;
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, there are some ways, but many of them require changing the layout, wrong data is send to the child of HorizontalScrollView mostly in the cases where there are children inside the child of HorizontalScrollView.

So i did things like this, instead of:

> <strike>val childA = horizontalScrollView.getChild(0)</strike>
>   <strike>childA.setOnTouchListener(this)</strike>

do

> horizontalScrollView.setOnTouchListener(this)

This way you have to calculate the clicks, and calls, but it works better than before to me, the scroll was slow and glitchy before.

```
var touchHistory=0
var lastTouchX=0f
override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event == null || v == null) return false
    when {
        event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            touchHistory=0
            lastTouchX=event.x
            // Screen1=0-480 / Screen2=0-2304 / ScrollPos=0-2304
            // Sample: 240 480 - 576 2304 = 240+576 = result
            val child = (v as HorizontalScrollView).getChildAt(0)
            val sXCurrent = event.x.toDouble()
            val sXMax = v.width.toDouble()
            val s2XCurrent = scrollX
            val s2XMax = child.width
            val clickPos = s2XCurrent+sXCurrent
            val result = clickPos/s2XMax
            // Do something

        }
        event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            if(touchHistory==0){
            //Click performed, do something
            }
            //if touchHistory > 0 is currently scrolling and click is omitted
            lastTouchX=event.x
            touchHistory=0
        }
        event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            if(event.x!=lastTouchX)touchHistory++ //Check wether is clicking or scrolling
            lastTouchX=event.x
        }
    }

    return false
}
```